# Display label on top of Bar chart in JFree

Tags: jfreechart

I want to display the labels on top of the bar in a multi series chart using JFree. Please tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

As this is a bar chart, add an instance of [`StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator.html) to your plot's renderer. See the source for the meaning of elements in the `labelFormat` string. Here's a related [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) using `StandardXYItemLabelGenerator`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean the legend, that can be easily placed on top in this way:

```
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.TOP);
```